# We do not authorize the use of this system to transport unsolicited, and/or bulk e-mail. gmail

Tags: php, email

I'm a developer with little knowledge on how email system works. My client has a gmail account that is being use as a bridge on all of website he has. All contact form on all website he managed send an email to his gmail account.

What he wants is to create a website that will retrieve all those emails and save them on his main site database something like pop3 or imap functionality. Incoming connection is ok but smtp outgoing email sending is not allowed on his server.

I have read some post that google does not allow unfamillar ips to send email using gmail account. I tried it locally and it works fine. Is there a way to send email using gmail account on any server or ip?

Comment: I guess this would be possible, but wouldn't it be simpler to put the data into the database directly from the forms?

Comment: you CAN retrieve data from gmail and you CAN send emails using gmail; all via PHP. I see no issues here.

Comment: I've already done the email downloading using php imap. The problem is when the code trying to connect on gmail using PHPMailer class for sending email it return an error "We do not authorize the use of this system to transport unsolicited, and/or bulk e-mail.". It seems that gmail does not allow the hosting server to send email using a gmail account.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless you plan to send tons of emails from your server or you're flagged as a spammer, you'll be able to send email through a gmail account.

If so, I recommend you to set 2FA on this account and use a application-specific password. So, your client's real password won't be stored on server.